# Не находит элемент Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, test-automation

[image: скрин страницы]

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.window.maximize
driver.navigate.to "http://www.starofservice.ca/"
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, 'html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[1]').click
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, 'html/body/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a').click
```

Пытаюсь написать тест по регистрации юзера. Ссылаюсь на элемент с помощью xpath, но, тест фейлиться, пишет, что не найдет такой элемент. 
Пробовал варианты **find_element** *:name, :link, :css* - не находит.
Пробовал вариант теста написать на **пайтоне**, на **джаве** - результат такой же.
При том, что если указываю на элемент слева (**create an account**) - все ок, без проблем идет каждый раз. А на элемент **create a Professional account** не хочет.
В чем может быть причина?
Ссылка на страницу?http://www.starofservice.ca/choose-account

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[text()='Registration']").click
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[text()='Create a Professional account']").click
```

1. Старайтесь в коде на Ruby использовать только двойные кавычки, а одинарные оставьте только на такие редкие случаи, как например второй аргумент .[g]sub с указанием номера группы.
2. Верстка может ездить, а текстовые якори, диктуемые начальством, оказываются менее изменчивы, поэтому привязывайтесь по `*[text()=`.

Comment: Спасибо, Nakilon, но, все равно не находит элемент. Вы пробовали прогнать тест и кнопка 'Create a Professional account' кликалась?

Comment: @Konstantin, да, на момент написания ответа все сработало. Если не забуду, проверю когда буду за другим компьютером, на случай, если на сайте внезапно сменилась верстка.

Comment: проблема в том, что при первом прогоне теста - элемент находит, при всех последующих - нет. Будет возможность - попробуйте 2-3 раза подряд прогнать тест.

Comment: Три раза прогнал -- все ок.